# /sbin/fsck.zfs_member not found while regenerating the initramfs

Tags: initramfs, zfs, 17.04

I'm running 17.04 on a zfs root. While running update-initramfs I receive a warning that may have no impact but I would look to be sure, and report upstream if the issue is not on my side. Is anyone having the same behavior ?

```
$ sudo update-initramfs -c -k all 
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.10.0-15-generic
Warning: /sbin/fsck.zfs_member doesn't exist, can't install to initramfs, ignoring.
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no fsck for ZFS.
So fsck has to be ignored.

ZFS-partitions are identified as `zfs_member` (to verify run `sudo lsblk -l` or `sudo blkid`). update-initramfs wants to install the appropriate fsck. That is not possible.

By the way: You can start a [deep check for a ZFS-pool](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19120-01/open.solaris/817-2271/gbbwa/index.html) manually using `sudo zpool scrub MyPoolName`.